# Best notation for the derivative?

Tags: soft-question, notation, partial-derivative

I define *best* as the simplest most consistent notation.

**Question:** What is the best derivative notation?

### Summary of what others have done:

Let $f$ be a function that maps any $(x,y)$ to $f(x,y)$.
I have seen the following with respect to the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$:

$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta x} f =
\frac{\delta f}{\delta x} =
\frac{\delta f(x,y)}{\delta x} =
\frac{\delta f}{\delta x} (x,y) =
f'_x =
f^{(1)}_x
$$

And the following for their 2nd derivative:
$$
\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^2} f =
\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta x^2} =
\frac{\delta^2 f(x,y)}{\delta x^2} =
\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta x^2} (x,y) =
f''_x =
f^{(2)}_x
$$

Then, if we wish to use such derivative functions later to find their value at some point $(x,y)$, we use:
$$
\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta x} f\right)(x,y) =
\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\right)(x,y) =
\left(\frac{\delta f(x,y)}{\delta x}\right)(x,y) =
\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x} (x)\right)(x,y) =
f'_x(x,y) =
f^{(1)}_x(x,y)
$$

But now there is a conflict between $x$ in the name of the derivative functions, and $x$ in the point $(x,y)$. To resolve this, we need to use some other name for the input point $(x,y)$, such as $(a,b)$ as follows
$$
\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta x} f\right)(a,b) =
\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\right)(a,b) =
\left(\frac{\delta f(x,y)}{\delta x}\right)(a,b) =
\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x} (x)\right)(a,b) =
f'_x(a,b) =
f^{(1)}_x(a,b)
$$

### What I have done:

I think the best notation for the partial derivative function is
$$
f^{(n)}_m
$$
where $n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ derivative, and $m$ denotes that the derivative is with respect to the $m^{th}$ argument of function $f$.

This is because of the fact that function arguments are addressed based on their order, not based on their names. E.g. $f(\pi, e)$ means that $\pi$ is fed as the first argument, and $e$ is fed as the 2nd argument.

More specifically my equivalent notation to $f''_x$ is:
$$
f^{(2)}_1
$$
since $x$ is the 1st argument.

This way, we could use $(x,y)$ as the input point without causing the confusion earlier:
$$
f^{(2)}_1(x,y)
$$

Another thought that I have is the following:
$$
f^{\nabla 2}_1
$$
which also relates to the gradient $\nabla f$, or the second gradient $\nabla^2 f$ (gradient of gradient) as follows:
$$
\nabla^2 f = f^{\nabla 2} = f^{\nabla 2}_1 \mathbf{\hat i} + f^{\nabla 2}_2 \mathbf{\hat j}
$$

**Update 1:** After thinking a bit more on mixed partial derivatives (thanks to the discussion with **@axiom_of_choice** under his answer), I found this idea to handle 1) mixed partial derivatives, as well as the case when $f$ takes highly dimensional input, e.g. $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{100})$:
$$
f'_{2,1}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{100})
$$
to denote the value that the mixed partial derivative maps against when given input $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{100})$. This is traditionally probably denoted by
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}f(x_{1,0}, x_{2,0}, \ldots, x_{100,0})
$$

More generally, I could say:
$$
f'_{2^2,1^5}
$$
to denote the $2+5=7^{th}$ mixed partial derivative, which is traditionally denoted by
$$
\frac{\partial^7}{\partial x_2^2 \partial x_1^5}f
$$

I also think using $f^{\nabla}$ instead of $\nabla f$, to denote the gradient, is better to avoid the confusion $\nabla f(x_1,\ldots)$ against $\nabla \big(f(x_1,\ldots)\big)$:
$$
\nabla \left(\frac{\partial^7}{\partial x_2^2 \partial x_1^5}f\right) = f^{\nabla}_{2^2,1^5} = f'_{1,2^2,1^5} \mathbf{\hat i_1} + f'_{2^3,1^5} \mathbf{\hat i_2} + \ldots + f'_{100,2^2,1^5} \mathbf{\hat i_{100}}
$$
where $\mathbf{\hat i_1}, \mathbf{\hat i_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{\hat i_{100}}$ are perpendicular unit vectors that make up the axis of a $100$-dimensional cartesian coordinate system.

If one really wants to say $\nabla \big(f(x_1,\ldots)\big)$, then I think this to be used: $f(x_1,\ldots)^{\nabla}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ since it easily allows the notation of mixed partial derivatives. (By the way the partial symbol is done by "\partial").

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by *mixed partial derivatives*?

Comment: For example take $f(x,y)=x\cdot y$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=y$ and $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}f(x,y)=0$ i.e. if you see $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ as a function of $(x,y)$ and do another partial derivative in the $x$ direction it is 0. But if you do $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y))=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y=1$. You call  $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x}f(x,y)$ a mixed partial derivative since you first derive in one direction and then in another.

Comment: @caveman,  the y partial of the x partial, for instance

Comment: @axiom_of_choice Thank you. Just to clarify for myself. In your notation, is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ a function? Or is it the value that the first partial derivative of $f$ maps to when given input $(x,y)$? I think some interpret this differently as "*the first derivative of the number (which is a constant) $f(x,y)$*" (since $f$ is a function, and $f(x,y)$ is a number that $f$ maps against when given input $(x,y)$.

Comment: Also, any thoughts on my alternatives $f''_{2,1} = f^{(2)}_{2,1} = f^{\nabla 2}_{2,1}$ to denote $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x}$ please? Thanks. Note that $2$ denotes $y$ since it's the 2nd argument of $f$.

Comment: You're right, this notation might be confusing but it is common. So actually if you want to have the first partial derivative at $(x_0,y_0)$ you write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x_0,y_0)$. The first partial derivative as a function would then map $(x_0,y_0)\mapsto\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x_0,y_0)$. If you really want to use your other notation of course you can do so as long as you state the meaning at the beginning, but i haven't seen them in any mathematical text i have  read (if you decide to use them i would use $f^{(2)}_{2,1}$ since it seems more natural to me).

Comment: @axiom_of_choice Thank you. Sorry for having too many questions. If your time allows, could you please explain how would your suggested notation work with the case where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ takes an $n$-dimensional input, where $n$ is a large number? Usually for such case, I think people give up on using letters $x,y,\ldots$ since $n > 26$ is possible, and instead use the notation $f(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{100})$, for example, to denote the value that $f$ maps against when given input $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{100})$?

Comment: @axiom_of_choice For example,  Would you write this $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0} f(x_{0,0},x_{1,0}, x_{2,0},\ldots,X_{100,0})$ to denote the value that the partial derivative maps against when given the specific point $(x_{0,0},x_{1,0}, x_{2,0},\ldots,X_{100,0})$?

Comment: You're right, though you should start counting at 1. Then you can also write something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(x)$.